# organizing colors in a pie chart in a specific sequence?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart, colormap

i have a dataframe that includes colors of vehicles. it looks similar to this:

```
    paint_color count
0   black       4821
1   blue        2850
2   brown       784
3   custom      755
4   green       887
5   grey        3221
6   orange      144
7   purple      66
8   red     2858
9   silver      4034
10  white       6096
11  yellow      127
```

i have imported pandas and matplotlib.pyplot (as plot)

i am plotting a pie chart to show the count of each color - and of course i'd really like the colors to correspond with the.. colors..  so i set up a dictionary of colors:

```
colors = ({'custom': 'black',"black": 'black', "blue": 'blue', "brown":'brown','custom': 'cyan',"green": 'green',"grey":'grey',"orange":'orange',"purple":'purple',"red":'red', "silver":'silver',"white":'gray',"yellow":'yellow'})
```

i then set out to plot using this code:

```
df.plot(kind='pie', y='count',figsize=(15,15), fontsize = 14,colors = colors)
```

but i get the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument:custom
```

now, if i do a query where i select all values except those for custom, the values line up the way i would expect them to (and it works fine)

what i am unsure of is - is the error being created because it doesn't recognize "custom"? as i've been reading on this error, it seems that it can be thrown by less obvious issues, so i'm wondering if that is what i'm facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write `df.plot.pie(..., colors=colors)`, a list of the keys of the dictionary is used. So, it would be just the same as `df.plot.pie(..., colors=['custom', 'black', 'blue', 'brown', 'green', 'grey', 'orange', 'purple', 'red', 'silver', 'white', 'yellow'])`. Apart from invalid color names, this also very heavily depends on the order o the keys of the dictionary compared to the order of the dataframe. Also, using `colors.values()` would give valid color names, but still has the problem of a mismatched ordering.

To work correctly, each value in the column needs to be mapped using the colors dictionary. Either via `df['paint_color'].map(colors)` or `[colors[p] for p in df['paint_color']]`.

If you set the 'paint_color' column as index, the pandas plotting will show this as labels. This helps to verify that the colors are correct.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df_str = '''    paint_color count
0   black       4821
1   blue        2850
2   brown       784
3   custom      755
4   green       887
5   grey        3221
6   orange      144
7   purple      66
8   red         2858
9   silver      4034
10  white       6096
11  yellow      127'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df_str), delim_whitespace=True)
colors = ({'custom': 'turquoise', 'black': 'black', 'blue': 'blue', 'brown': 'brown', 'green': 'green',
           'grey': 'grey', 'orange': 'orange', 'purple': 'purple', 'red': 'red', 'silver': 'silver',
           'white': 'antiquewhite', 'yellow': 'yellow'})

df.set_index('paint_color').plot(kind='pie', y='count', figsize=(15, 15), fontsize=14,
                                 colors=[colors[p] for p in df['paint_color']])
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

PS: Note that in the dictionary of the question, the key `'custom'`appears two times. Once at the first spot with value `'black'` and once at the sixth place with value `'cyan'`.

A list of valid color names can be found at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors).

The thin lines between the pie wedges can be annoying, especially for thin wedges. The line width can be set to zero to remove them:

```py
df.set_index('paint_color').plot(kind='pie', y='count', figsize=(15, 15), fontsize=14,
                                 colors=df['paint_color'].map(colors), wedgeprops={'linewidth': 0})
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be passing the values of the dictionary instead of their keys, otherwise you are passing "custom" and python wouldn't recognize it. I would suggest you try this:

```
df.plot(kind='pie', y='count',figsize=(15,15), fontsize = 14,colors = colors.values())
```

Comment: @seuadr Are you sure the colors are applied in the correct order? With the example code, this would color the wedges `black, black, blue, brown, cyan, ...` instead of `black, blue, brown, ...`